# How to Get Latitude and Longitude from the Polyline Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

I'm trying get the latitude and longitude of a polyline.

Below is the code sample by which I'm creating the Polyline object, It's working.

```
var startLat = parseFloat(lineSplit[7]);
var startLng = parseFloat(lineSplit[8]);
var endLat = parseFloat(lineSplit[19]);
var endLng = parseFloat(lineSplit[20]);
var polyCoordinates = new Array();

polyCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(startLat,startLng));
polyCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(endLat,endLng));
polyLinesArr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(startLat,startLng));
polyLinesArr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(endLat,endLng));

polyPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: polyCoordinates,
geodesic: true,
strokeColor: '#060AB1',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
});
Coordinates.push(polyPath);
```

Below is the piece of the code using which I'm trying to fetch the latitude and longitude of the Polyline object.

```
for (i=0; i<Coordinates.length; i++) 
{                           
    //alert(map.getBounds().contains(Coordinates[i].getPosition()));
    //alert(JSON.stringify(Coordinates[i]));
    alert(Coordinates[i].latitude + " , " + Coordinates[i].longitude);
    alert(Coordinates[i].get('Latitude') + " , " + Coordinates[i].get('Longitude'));
    Coordinates[i].setMap(map); //or Coordinates[i].setMap(null);
}
```

To display the polylines on the map `Coordinates[i].setMap(map); //or Coordinates[i].setMap(null);` line worked. But I need to display the Latitude and Longitude the Polyline that is drawn on the map.

For getting the Polylines latitude and longitude, I googled and gone through some of the posts in the Stackoverflow and found following methods that can used to fetch the latitude and longitude from the polyline object.

> alert(Coordinates[i].latitude);
>
> alert(Coordinates[i].longitude);
>
> alert(Coordinates[i].get('Latitude'));
>
> alert(Coordinates[i].get('Longitude'));

But unfortunately none of the above worked. Please help me in finding out the way to get the latitude and longitude from the polyline object.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) the polyline's coordinates can be retrieved using the `.getPath()` method of the `google.maps.Polyline`.

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41, -70),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var startLat = 42;
  var startLng = -72;
  var endLat = 40;
  var endLng = -70;
  var polyCoordinates = new Array();

  polyCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLng));
  polyCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(endLat, endLng));


  polyPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: polyCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#060AB1',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < polyPath.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polyPath.getPath().getAt(i));
    console.log(polyPath.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me in getting near to answer. However I needed the Start lat and lng along with End lat lng of a polyline. I got it using getArray() method and then further stringyfying the array to json and parsing the json formatted data. Thank you again for you help.